# angular router doesn't activate ngoninit

Tags: angular, signalr, angular-router, ngoninit

I have an angular app which suppose to create a GUI for users to log in.
I have a log in component with the following html code

```
<mat-card>
  <mat-form-field class="full-width">
    <input matInput placeholder="Enter your Username" [(ngModel)]="username">
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field class="full-width">
    <input matInput placeholder="Enter Password" [(ngModel)]="password">
  </mat-form-field>

  <button mat-raised-button (click)="logIn()">Log In</button>
</mat-card>
```

This is the code for the component

```
@Hub({hubName: 'DALHub'})
export class LogInComponent implements OnInit {
  private hubWrapper: HubWrapper;
  username: String = '';
  password: String = '';

  constructor(private router: Router, private hub: HubService) {
    // This is signalr init process
    this.hubWrapper = this.hub.register(this);
    this.hub.connect({url: 'http://localhost:10476/signalr'});
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  logIn() {
    this.hubWrapper.invoke('LogIn', this.username, this.password);
  }

  @HubSubscription()
  LogOK() {
    this.hubWrapper.unregister();
    this.router.navigate(['logged', this.username, this.password]);
  }
}
```

As you can see I am using a signalr server and the package ngx-signalr for a client.

once the user clicks the "Log In" button the logIn function is activated which calls the server to check if the username and password are correct.
If the password and username are correct the server calls the function LogOK in the client which suppose to route the app to a different component.

This is the router configuration

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: LogInComponent},
  {path: 'logged/:username/:password', component: UserComponent}
];
```

(NOTE the router-outlet is in the app html page)

This is the log in view [image: log in component]
when I log in I expect to get the following page
[image: UserComponent]
However when I log in I get the following page
[image: LogIn results]
As you can see the login page is still here and the user page looks weird, I checked and I saw that the ngOnInit function of the UserComponent wasn't being activated and I think that is the problem.
Do you know how I can fix it?

Comment: do you get a call to the LogOK() function

Comment: Yes, I've tried that and when I call this function myself(from the component itself and not the server) it does work but I don't know why

Comment: I have not used 'ngx-signalr', but I would think it could be the function scope... try to make a console.log('HubSubscription', this) in your LogOK function to check the scope

Comment: Tried that also, when I printed the scope using console.log(this) and I saw its a logInCoponent

Comment: any chance `this.hubWrapper.unregister();` could be interfering ?

Comment: No it didn't change anything

Comment: @Yedidyakfir is [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-signalr) the aforementioned npm package?

Comment: No, [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-signalr-hubservice) is

Comment: Anyone else a little disconcerted about passing the password on the URL?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the routing path is wrong so change the route in `login component` like this

```
const url = `${'logged/' + this.username + '/' + this.password}`;
this.router.navigate([url]);
```

Comment: I've tried that and it didn't word, also keep in mind that I can see the router navigated to the correct path (it the browser's url) but it still didn't activated the ngoninit function

Answer (score 0):

**Route Configuration**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: LogInComponent},
  {path: 'logged/:username/:password', component: UserComponent}
];
```

**Route navigation/activation**

```
this.router.navigate(['/logged', this.username, this.password]);
```

Looks like you are missing the slash? Notice the slash at the front of the path.

From the docs:

> While building out the crisis center feature, you navigated to the
>   crisis detail route using an absolute path that begins with a slash.
>
> The router matches such absolute paths to routes starting from the top
>   of the route configuration.

Also, you could consider turning on route tracing so you can better see what may be wrong with your routes:

```
RouterModule.forRoot([routes], { enableTracing: true })
```

Comment: Are you certain? when I tried to add the slash I got "Invalid configuration error"
I Also tried to enable tracing but I didn't saw anything out of the ordinary

Comment: Yes, I'm certain ... but I put it in the wrong place in my example. :-(. Sorry about that. I'll fix it now.

Comment: It didn't help, I am using both css files and scss files, could this be the source of the problem?